# Do I need do wrap an <svg> with <button> to indicate it is a button?

Tags: html, button, svg, structured-data

So basically I have the following markup:

```
<button type="button"> <svg class="search"> ... </svg> </button>
```

The SVG itself does not indicate that it is a clickable element, but a button does. So for screen-readers (or blind people) it could be an improvement. Am I correct?

Comment: "Indicate it is a button" to whom?  It's not clear what you are asking.  You can add a click event handler to an SVG to make it act like a button, but I don't know whether that answers your question or not.

Comment: Thanks, I made my question more clearly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no reason you cannot put an SVG in a `<button>` element.  Or you can add the attribute `role="button"` to tell screen readers that it is a button.

```
<svg class="search" role="button">...</svg>
```